# adding single element to a List in a NavigableMap

Tags: java

I want to be able to sort files based on what day they were entered into a Map.  The key is the day, and the value is a List of n Files added on the respective day.  However, I need to be able to add the files to the List one at a time - but I'm stuck on the syntax.  How do I call List.add() from within Map.put()?  Here's my code:

```
public static NavigableMap<String, List<File>> myFiles = new TreeMap<>();
String today = new Date().toString();
File currentFile;
myFiles.put(today, currentFile);  //problem here adding currentFile
```

Comment: You have to check whether there is a list already there. Or use a `MultiMap` from Guava or Apache Commons Collections.

Comment: I'm really not clear on what you're asking...

Comment: I need multiple files to share the same key in a NavigableMap, but I want to add the files one at a time, as they are created, not as a collection at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of type safetyp (using generics). `today` points to a list of files and you want to just add one file to that list.

I would recommend you to first check if `today` is in the map and if it isn't add the backing list, then, add the `currentFile` to that list:

```
if (!myFiles.containsKey(today))
    myFiles.put(today, new ArrayList<File>());

myFiles.get(today).add(currentFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have two levels, so that first you check if there is already a list for that day, otherwise you create an empty one and add it to the set.

```
void addFile(File file)
{
  String today = new Date().toString();
  List<File> listForDay = myFiles.get(today);

  // if there are no files for today then create and empty list for the day
  if (listForDay == null)
  {
    listForDay = new ArrayList<File>();
    myFiles.put(today, listForDay);
  }

  listForDay.add(file);
}
```